# Square Payment Form Request Card Nonce not working in versions of safari

Tags: asp.net-mvc, safari, payment-processing, square

I seem to be having an issue with the requestCardNonce() function for some safari users This is using the Javascript API in my .net MVC application.

The current version I'm testing on appears to be working (13.0.4) but users are still reporting an inability to complete their orders with previous versions of safari. When filling in their information they're able to see the dialog that contains the fields for the Card Name, Number, CVV, and Postal code and expiration date but can't seem to proceed to the next dialog. The onGetCardNonce(event) function seems to be having issues executing properly.
The code I have currently looked like this

```
        if (gateway == "Square Payment Gateway") {
            paymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({
                applicationId: appId,
                inputClass: 'sq-input',
                autoBuild: false,
                cardNumber: {
                    elementId: 'sq-card-number',
                    placeholder: 'Card Number'
                },
                cvv: {
                    elementId: 'sq-cvv',
                    placeholder: 'CVV'
                },
                expirationDate: {
                    elementId: 'sq-expiration-date',
                    placeholder: 'MM/YY'
                },
                postalCode: {
                    elementId: 'sq-postal-code',
                    placeholder: 'Postal'
                },

                // SqPaymentForm callback functions
                callbacks: {
                    cardNonceResponseReceived: function (errors, nonce, cardData) {
                        let errMsg = "";
                        if (errors) {
                            // Log errors from nonce generation to the browser developer console.
                            console.error('Encountered errors:');
                            errors.forEach(function (error) {
                                console.error('  ' + error.message);
                                errMsg += '   ' + error.message;
                            });
                            alert('Encountered errors' + errMsg);
                            return;
                        }
                        $("#CardNumber").val(cardData["last_4"]);
                        $("#squareToken").val(nonce)

                        $("#form-container").dialog("close");
                        var isValid = true;

                        $('#CardName,#CardNumber').each(function () {
                            if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                                isValid = false;
                                $(this).css({
                                    "border": "",
                                    "background": ""
                                });
                            }
                            else {
                                $(this).css({
                                    "border": "",
                                    "background": ""
                                });
                            }
                        });

                        if ($("#Total").val() == "0.00" || $("#Total").val() == "0")
                            isValid = true;

                        if (isValid == false) {
                            $('#PayCreditCard')[0].disabled = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");

                            // Open Terms & Conditions
                            $("#dvTermsConditions").dialog("open");
                            $("#dvTermsConditions").dialog({
                                autoOpen: false,
                                modal: true,
                                buttons: {
                                    "Proceed": function () {

                                        if ($('#AgreeToTerms').is(':checked')) {
                                            $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
                                            $(this).dialog("close");
                                            $("#frmCheckOut").submit();

                                        }
                                        else {
                                            alert("You must agree to the terms & conditions.");
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "Cancel": function () {
                                        $('#PayCreditCard')[0].disabled = false;
                                        $(this).dialog("close");
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            paymentForm.build();

            function onGetCardNonce(event) {
                // Don't submit the form until SqPaymentForm returns with a nonce
                event.preventDefault();
                // Request a nonce from the SqPaymentForm object
                paymentForm.requestCardNonce();
            }

            function closeCC() {
                $("#form-container").dialog("close");
            }
        }
```

Originally the issue was that payment form was not found so I moved the definition of that outside the if statement and that seemed to clear up the issue for safari 13.0.4+

Does anyone have suggestions on how to make the square payment form (v2) work on all (or at least the last 3+ years) of versions of Safari (not on mobile)?

Comment: Do you have any browser console logs from when it happens, to see if there's any errors? Also, I'm not entirely sure what all browsers are currently supported, but are you utilizing `isSupportedBrowser` function, to ensure the browser version is actually supported? https://developer.squareup.com/docs/api/paymentform#isSupportedBrowser

Comment: We don't have browser logs at the moment as we're having difficulty tracking which safari version the error is occurring in. For the isSupportedBrowser function do you know how it determines true or false? Like is there a list somewhere in the API code for that?